# LiipFunctionalTestBundle Mock service in runCommand

Tags: mocking, testng, symfony

I want to test the command in Symfony using LiipFunctionalTestBundle. The command, as a result, sends e-mail. I would like to check if either send was executed in mailer service, or method in my repository was run.

The test fails as setAsNotified is not executed but it is.

```php
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Command\NewMessageEmailCommand;

use Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class NewMessageEmailCommandTest extends WebTestCase
{

public function setUp()
{
    $this->fixtures = $this->loadFixtureFiles(array(
        '@AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/users.yml',
        '@AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/messages.yml',
    ));
}

public function testExecute()
{
    $kernel = $this->createKernel();
    $kernel->boot();

    $msgRep = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')->getRepository('AppBundle:Message');
    $stub2 = $this->getMockBuilder(get_class($msgRep))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['setAsNotified'])
        ->getMock();

    $stub2->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
        ->method('setAsNotified')
        ->willReturn(true);


    $this->runCommand('email:message_received:send',[
       '--limit' => 1
    ], true);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to test your command would be to move your command's logic inside a service. The service would be way easier to test than the SF command.